# How do I zoom out on the react-native-maps using xcode simulator?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

zooming in is fine with double click on the mouse, but yes I cant zoom out, any help?
Thank you

Comment: Press alt to enable pinch

Comment: Hi, yes when I do that the two grey markers appear and the move inwards like pinching but the map is not zooming out.

Comment: You can try using double tap:
1. Move the cursor over the map 
2. Double click on the map area and don‘t release second press
3. Drag the cursor upwards/downwards